# When a host was added to Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

It is possible to know when a host was inserted to zabbix for monitoring?

I need to check how many hosts were added into my zabbix in the last two months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Zabbix 2.x : Administration / Audit

On Zabbix 3.x : Reports / Audit

Filter on Action: Add and Resource: Host